# What's a reasonable threshold for UVLO?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo

I see that the [TPS61093](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61093.pdf) UVLO is triggered at 1.55V. However, this [boost converter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10255) has a threshold of 2.6V. Is 1.55V a bit too low for lipo? If so, how come the TPS61093 is designed this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 1.55V is way too low for Li-Ion/LiPo. 2.6V is already on the very edge.

It has 1.55V UVLO because it works correctly down to 1.6V.

Not every single device in the world is designed to work with Li-Ion and only Li-Ion. If a converter says you could use a battery type that doesn't mean it will also suddenly do everything that the battery needs in ways of protection.

The main difference here is the presence of a PCB with many components vs just a chip.

Comment: Right. On the other hand, is the 1.1A peak overcurrent protection reasonable for lipo though?

Comment: @Kar For a 1.1Ah LiPo? For a 100mAh LiPo?

Comment: For a 18650. All 18650 can comfortably output 1100mA, right?

Comment: @Kar Should be, if they are properly manufactured by a reliable source. If they are $1 cells you may get lucky or very unlucky in that respect.